Cannot customize HTTP API Gateway generated with NET Lambda Annotations Framework
Let's say I have following GET endpoint.
[LambdaFunction]
[HttpApi(LambdaHttpMethod.Get, "/info")]
public string FunctionHandler(ILambdaContext context)
{
    return "OK";
}

serverless.template is generated and behind the scenes CloudFormation generates HTTP API Gateway, Integrations and Routes and eveything works as a charm:
"TestFunctionFunctionHandlerGenerated": {
  "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
  "Metadata": {
    "Tool": "Amazon.Lambda.Annotations",
    "SyncedEvents": [
      "RootGet"
    ],
    "SyncedEventProperties": {
      "RootGet": [
        "Path",
        "Method"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Properties": {
    "Runtime": "dotnet8",
    "CodeUri": ".",
    "MemorySize": 512,
    "Timeout": 30,
    "Policies": [
      "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
    ],
    "PackageType": "Zip",
    "Handler": "Test::Test.Function_FunctionHandler_Generated::FunctionHandler",
    "FunctionName": "TestGetInfo",
    "Events": {
      "RootGet": {
        "Type": "HttpApi",
        "Properties": {
          "Path": "/info",
          "Method": "GET"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


However, when attempting to customize HTTP API Gateway like simple CorsConfiguration or attach JWT authorizer, I was not able to do that.
I have attempted to "add" HTTP API gateway which would match existing one logical id and then reference it in my "endpoint", but it does not work (see edit 2024-07-07 below).
The only way to achieve what I want is to let Annotations Framework generate function part and then manually create api gateway, route, integration and bindings, which is overhead to my mind as you lose all the benefits which annotations provide.
Following configuration works, but it is just ridiculous to my mind:
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "This template is partially managed by Amazon.Lambda.Annotations (v1.5.0.0).",
  "Resources": {
    "TestApi": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": "Test-api",
        "ProtocolType": "HTTP",
        "CorsConfiguration": {
          "AllowOrigins": [
            "*"
          ],
          "AllowMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "OPTIONS",
            "PUT",
            "PATCH"
          ],
          "AllowHeaders": [
            "Content-Type",
            "Authorization"
          ],
          "MaxAge": 600
        }
      }
    },
    "TestApiIntegration": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration",
      "Properties": {
        "ApiId": {
          "Ref": "TestApi"
        },
        "IntegrationType": "AWS_PROXY",
        "IntegrationUri": {
          "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${TestFunctionFunctionHandlerGenerated.Arn}/invocations"
        },
        "PayloadFormatVersion": "2.0"
      }
    },
    "TestApiRoute": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route",
      "Properties": {
        "ApiId": {
          "Ref": "TestApi"
        },
        "RouteKey": "GET /info",
        "Target": {
          "Fn::Sub": "integrations/${TestApiIntegration}"
        }
      }
    },
    "TestApiDeployment": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Deployment",
      "Properties": {
        "ApiId": {
          "Ref": "TestApi"
        }
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "TestApiRoute"
      ]
    },
    "TestApiStage": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage",
      "Properties": {
        "ApiId": {
          "Ref": "TestApi"
        },
        "StageName": "prod",
        "DeploymentId": {
          "Ref": "TestApiDeployment"
        },
        "AutoDeploy": true
      }
    },
    "TestFunctionFunctionHandlerGenerated": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Metadata": {
        "Tool": "Amazon.Lambda.Annotations",
        "SyncedEvents": [
          "RootGet"
        ],
        "SyncedEventProperties": {
          "RootGet": [
            "Path",
            "Method"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Properties": {
        "Runtime": "dotnet8",
        "CodeUri": ".",
        "MemorySize": 512,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Policies": [
          "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
        ],
        "PackageType": "Zip",
        "Handler": "Test::Test.Function_FunctionHandler_Generated::FunctionHandler",
        "FunctionName": "TestGetInfo"
        "Events": {
          "RootGet": {
            "Type": "HttpApi",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/info",
              "Method": "GET",
              "ApiId": {
                "Ref": "TestApi"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "TestApi": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "${TestApi}"
      },
      "Export": {
        "Name": "TestApi"
      }
    },
    "HttpApiGatewayUrl": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${TestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com"
      }
    }
  }
}

EDIT 2024-07-07
CloudFormation stack info:



Logical ID
Physical ID
Type
Status




ServerlessHttpApi
MASKED
AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
CREATE_COMPLETE


ServerlessHttpApiApiGatewayDefaultStage
$default
AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage
CREATE_COMPLETE


TestFunctionFunctionHandlerGenerated
TestGetInfo
AWS::Lambda::Function
CREATE_COMPLETE


TestFunctionFunctionHandlerGeneratedRole
MASKED
AWS::IAM::Role
CREATE_COMPLETE


TestFunctionFunctionHandlerGeneratedRootGetPermission
MASKED
AWS::Lambda::Permission
CREATE_COMPLETE



Full serverless.template:
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "This template is partially managed by Amazon.Lambda.Annotations (v1.5.0.0).",
  "Resources": {
    "ServerlessHttpApi": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": "test-api",
        "ProtocolType": "HTTP",
        "CorsConfiguration": {
          "AllowOrigins": [
            "*"
          ],
          "AllowMethods": [
            "POST"
          ],
          "AllowHeaders": [
            "Content-Type",
            "Authorization"
          ],
          "MaxAge": 600
        }
      }
    },
    "TestFunctionFunctionHandlerGenerated": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Metadata": {
        "Tool": "Amazon.Lambda.Annotations",
        "SyncedEvents": [
          "RootGet"
        ],
        "SyncedEventProperties": {
          "RootGet": [
            "Path",
            "Method"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Properties": {
        "Runtime": "dotnet8",
        "CodeUri": ".",
        "MemorySize": 512,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Policies": [
          "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
        ],
        "PackageType": "Zip",
        "Handler": "Test::Test.Function_FunctionHandler_Generated::FunctionHandler",
        "FunctionName": "TestGetInfo",
        "Events": {
          "RootGet": {
            "Type": "HttpApi",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/info",
              "Method": "GET",
              "ApiId": {
                "Ref": "ServerlessHttpApi"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "HttpApiGatewayUrl": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessHttpApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com"
      }
    }
  }
}

Even though CORS settings is set to accept POST request only (testing purposes), my GET request passes and returns "OK". In my AWS console UI I cannot see any changes as well.
https://${ServerlessHttpApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/info

You say "Does not work".  What is error message?  What is the status that is returned from the request?  Do you get error messages at the server?

No errors, so I’d say it is silent fail. After executing Publish lambda via Visual Studio, it publishes lambda and triggers CloudFormation update. It is successful, however changes for API GW are not displayed in AWS console UI. I am assuming, the configuration is overwritten in the background as initially this gateway was created with annotations framework

You are making an HTTP connection and getting a response with no data.  You need to find the status that is returned in the response.  You could be getting a 400 error where the server is not accepting the request because you request is invalid.  You could be getting an error because you do not have the credentials to get the data (/info).  Or the query is not returning any data.  You server (controller) has base classes that automatically handles error cases unless you override the base class.  Can you put a break point on the return "ok" and reach the break point?

If you talk about HTTP GET request to /info endpoint, the return code is 200. I have updated my post (EDIT 2024-07-07) where I have listed everything I have, so that it would be easy to replicate or notice any error.
